# how to pass value from input field to form action url as parameter on type

Tags: javascript, jquery

any one here to help me on to copy Phone_Number value to p1 on url, when users enters phone number
this is my form action

```
<form action="https://shortcode.aspx?sms=LEAD&amp;p1=Phone_Number" method="post">
<input type="number" id="mobile" name="Phone_Number" required="">
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried tho?

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there. Instead of method `POST`, use `GET` and you have it

```
<form action="https://shortcode.aspx?sms=LEAD" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="sms" value="LEAD"/>
    <input type="number" id="mobile" name="p1" required="">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```